# How to filter an object array if the value of an object match array

Tags: javascript

I have the following object table :

```
 let data = [
   {key:"20-09-2019", skill: [{id: 500, message: "monday"}, {id: 501, message: "tuesday"}]},
   {key:"21-09-2019", skill: [{id: 502, message: "thursday"}, {id: 503, message: "sunday"}]},
   {key:"22-09-2019", skill: [{id: 504, message: "sunday"}]},
]
```

let search = "sun"

I would like to filter the table if the value of "message" match with the value of "search"

if search = "sun" the filter should return the following result:

result after filter :

```
 data = [
   {key:"21-09-2019", skill: [ {id: 503, message: "sunday"}]},
   {key:"22-09-2019", skill: [{id: 504, message: "sunday"}]},
]
```

here the array only returns the objects having the message value that match with "sun"

I know the filter method but I do not think we can do a filter in a filter.

I also know the method that allows me to match the message :

```
 message.toLowerCase().includes(search);
```

but I do not know how to filter the object array, if anyone has an idea?

Comment: @ponury-kostek  this is a little different because I do not filter at the first level but in the second table

Comment: `data.map(item=>({...item, skill=>skill.filter(s=>s.message.includes(search))}).filter(item=>item.skill.length)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create new objects without mutating the original data and return only the parts who contain the wanted sub string.

```js
function filter(array, value) {
    function subFind(array, [key, ...keys]) {
        return keys.length
            ? array
                  .map(o => {
                      var temp = subFind(o[key], keys);
                      return temp.length && Object.assign({}, o, { [key]: temp });
                  })
                  .filter(Boolean)
            : array.filter(o => o[key].includes(value));
    }
    return subFind(array, ['skill', 'message']);
}

let data = [{ key: "20-09-2019", skill: [{ id: 500, message: "monday" }, { id: 501, message: "tuesday" } ]}, { key: "21-09-2019", skill: [{ id: 502, message: "thursday" }, { id: 503, message: "sunday" } ]}, { key: "22-09-2019", skill: [{ id: 504, message: "sunday" }] }];

console.log(filter(data, 'sun'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can filter on `skill` field of each element by search value first then filter elements that still have skill.

```js
let search = "sun";
let data = [
   {key:"20-09-2019", skill: [{id: 500, message: "monday"}, {id: 501, message: "tuesday"}]},
   {key:"21-09-2019", skill: [{id: 502, message: "thursday"}, {id: 503, message: "sunday"}]},
   {key:"22-09-2019", skill: [{id: 504, message: "sunday"}]},
];
data.forEach(el => {
  el.skill = el.skill.filter(s => s.message.toLowerCase().includes(search))
});
let result = data.filter(el => el.skill.length);
console.log(result)
```

Edit for not mutate the original array:

```js
let search = "sun";
let data = [
  {key:"20-09-2019", skill: [{id: 500, message: "monday"}, {id: 501, message: "tuesday"}]},
  {key:"21-09-2019", skill: [{id: 502, message: "thursday"}, {id: 503, message: "sunday"}]},
  {key:"22-09-2019", skill: [{id: 504, message: "sunday"}]},
    ];
let result = data.reduce((acc, {skill, ...rest}) => {
   skill = skill.filter(s => s.message.toLowerCase().includes(search));
   if(skill.length) acc.push({skill, ...rest});
   return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just fyi, this mutates `data`. However, for whatever reason, mutating `data` is probably what OP wants anyway...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you but the OP didn't mention that need to keep the `data`.

Comment: Avoiding mutations if you do not have to mutate is a best practice.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not think we can do a filter in a filter.

Yes you can but I would use `forEach()`. Example below.

```js
let data = [
   {key:"20-09-2019", skill: [{id: 500, message: "monday"}, {id: 501, message: "tuesday"}]},
   {key:"21-09-2019", skill: [{id: 502, message: "thursday"}, {id: 503, message: "sunday"}]},
   {key:"22-09-2019", skill: [{id: 504, message: "sunday"}]},
]

let search = 'sunday';
let result = [];

data.forEach(row=>{
  let found = row.skill.filter((skill=>skill.message === search));
  if (found.length) result.push({key:row.key,skill:found});
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
let data = [
   {key:"20-09-2019", skill: [{id: 500, message: "monday"}, {id: 501, message: "tuesday"}]},
   {key:"21-09-2019", skill: [{id: 502, message: "thursday"}, {id: 503, message: "sunday"}]},
   {key:"22-09-2019", skill: [{id: 504, message: "sunday"}]},
];

let search = "sun"

const newItems = data.filter(item => item.skill.filter(sk => sk.message.includes(search)).length);
newItems.forEach(item => {
  item.skill = item.skill.filter(x => x.message.includes(search))
})
```

Comment: This will still keep the `thursday` item in the output

Comment: @MihirKale the final table should only keep messages with "sunday"

Comment: see updated code @adiga